# Inheriting/sharing code across two Ruby modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module, dry

Noob here, looking for help DRYing this up. Let's say I have `module DoAThing` that looks like this:

```
module DoAThing
  class ExportNames
    def initialize(names, limit = 1000)
      @names = names
      @limit = limit
    end

    def perform
      awesome = ::ClassAwesome.sort_names(names, per_page: @limit)
      awesome.generate_export(::ClassAwesome::EXPORT_DEFAULTS)
    end
  end
end
```

And then I want to add a module that does the exact same thing except when it comes to generating a report, I want to pass a different constant, so something like this:

```
module DoASlightDifferentThing
  class ExportNames
    def initialize(names, limit = 1000)
      @names = names
      @limit = limit
    end

    def perform
      awesome = ::ClassAwesome.sort_names(names, per_page: @limit)
      awesome.generate_export(::ClassAwesome::DIFFERENT_EXPORT_DEFAULTS)
    end
  end
end
```

How can I elegantly DRY this up? Literally all I need to be able to do is pass in a different constant, namely I want to swap `EXPORT_DEFAULTS` for `DIFFERENT_EXPORT_DEFAULTS`

Comment: Why is `ClassAwesome` defining these constants? This binding seems unnatural to me. Why not allow the `ExportNames`  to define them instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually called “a dependency injection” and there are many articles on the subject over the internet. The main approach would be to accept a parameter in the call to `#perform` method:

```
module DoManyDifferentThings
  class ExportNames
    def initialize(names, limit = 1000)
      @names = names
      @limit = limit
    end

    def perform(report)
      awesome = ::ClassAwesome.sort_names(names, per_page: @limit)
      awesome.generate_export(report)
    end
  end
end
```

and call it like:

```
DoManyDifferentThings::ExportNames.perform(
  ::ClassAwesome::EXPORT_DEFAULTS
)
```

---

Whether the report method is supposed to have a predefined signature, one might go with class inheritance:

```
module DoManyDifferentThings
  class ExportNames
    def initialize(names, limit = 1000)
      @names = names
      @limit = limit
    end

    def perform
      awesome = ::ClassAwesome.sort_names(names, per_page: @limit)
      awesome.generate_export(self.class.constant_get('REPORT'))
    end
  end

  class ExportNames1 < ExportNames
    REPORT = ::ClassAwesome::EXPORT_DEFAULTS_1
  end

  class ExportNames1 < ExportNames
    REPORT = ::ClassAwesome::EXPORT_DEFAULTS_2
  end
end
```

or, as an alternative, one might declare a method to be overwritten in descendants:

```
module DoManyDifferentThings
  class ExportNames
    def initialize(names, limit = 1000)
      @names = names
      @limit = limit
    end

    def perform
      awesome = ::ClassAwesome.sort_names(names, per_page: @limit)
      awesome.generate_export(report)
    end

    protected

    def report
      raise "DO NOT CALL ME DIRECTLY"
    end
  end

  class ExportNames1 < ExportNames
    def report
      ::ClassAwesome::EXPORT_DEFAULTS_1
    end
  end

  class ExportNames2 < ExportNames
    def report
      ::ClassAwesome::EXPORT_DEFAULTS_2
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: dependency injection is exactly the way I was thinking of going about it too. glad I scrolled down this far because I would not have bothered with such a detailed explanation.

Comment: @engineersmnky apparently somebody had this answer downvoted, so maybe the explanation is _too damn boring detailed_ :)

Answer (score 2):

Either you move this constant as a parameter or you can use ihneritance.

**Provide defaults as a parameter**

```
module DoAThing
  class ExportNames
    def initialize(names, limit = 1000, defaults = ::ClassAwesome::EXPORT_DEFAULTS)
      @names = names
      @limit = limit
      @defaults = defaults
    end

    def perform
      awesome = ::ClassAwesome.sort_names(names, per_page: @limit)
      awesome.generate_export(@defaults)
    end
  end
end
```

Instead of calling DoASlightDifferentThing::ExportNames, you do:

```
DoAThing::ExportNames.perform_now(names, 1000, ::ClassAwesome::DIFFERENT_EXPORT_DEFAULTS)
```

**Ihneritance**

Or you can use ihneritance where we add a default method which will be overriden:

```
module DoAThing
  class ExportNames
    def initialize(names, limit = 1000)
      @names = names
      @limit = limit
    end

    def perform
      awesome = ::ClassAwesome.sort_names(names, per_page: @limit)
      awesome.generate_export(defaults)
    end

    def defaults
      ::ClassAwesome::EXPORT_DEFAULTS
    end
  end
end

module DoASlightDifferentThing
  class ExportNames < DoAThing::ExportNames
    def defaults
      ::ClassAwesome::DIFFERENT_EXPORT_DEFAULTS
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the namespace for both the classes can be same than I would have clean up the code by rewriting the code like this

```
module DoAThing
  class ExportNames
    def initialize(names, limit = 1000)
      @names = names
      @limit = limit
    end

    def perform(value)
      awesome = ::ClassAwesome.sort_names(names, per_page: @limit)
      awesome.generate_export(value)
    end
  end
end
```

Now I would call

```
DoAThing::ExportNames.new('your names').perform(::ClassAwesome::EXPORT_DEFAULTS)
DoAThing::ExportNames.new('your names').perform(::ClassAwesome::DIFFERENT_EXPORT_DEFAULTS)
```